# write char[] to NSOutputStream and read from NSInputStream

Tags: objective-c, c

I am trying to write to NSoutputStream as below:

```
+(void)write:(char[])data
{
    int size=(sizeof data) / (sizeof data[0]);
    [outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)data maxLength:size];
}
```

is this right?  Also how can I read NSInputStream into an char[].

Comment: "Also how can I read NSInputStream into an char[]" - how about reading the documentation of `NSInputStream`?

Comment: [NSInputStream Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't right. [Arrays are not pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html), hence the `sizeof()` operator here doesn't do what you think it does. Use an explicit `length` argument.

(Furthermore, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you don't have to spell it out.)